# Unexpected results when using scipy.interpolate.griddata

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

When I need to interpolate data in Python, I generally use my own implementation of the bilinear and bicubic routines from *Numerical recipes in C* (W.H. Press, 1992). The main reason for this is that I don't get what I would expect from Scipy. Since I now need more flexibility (for example, irregular grids), I'd like to use the `griddata` function.

My problem can be illustrated by the following script:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

from interp import *    # My own interpolation functions (from Press. 1992)

# Create test data
nPts = 50
color_ticks = np.linspace(0., 6., 50, endpoint = True)

pts1 = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4],
                 [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4],
                 [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4],
                 [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4]])*2 + 3.3

z1 = np.array([[1], [6], [4], [5], [2],
               [2], [3], [2], [4], [1],
               [4], [5], [1], [2], [1],
               [6], [2], [5], [3], [6]], dtype = np.float64)

# Interpolation coordinates
xi, yi = np.linspace(0,3,nPts)*2 + 3.3, np.linspace(0,4,nPts)*2 + 3.3

# Scipy, bilinear
scipy_linear = griddata((pts1[:,0], pts1[:,1]), z1, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method = 'linear')

# Scipy, bicubic
scipy_cubic = griddata((pts1[:,0], pts1[:,1]), z1, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method = 'cubic')

# Press, bilinear
pts2 = np.zeros((nPts*nPts,2))

for i in range(0, nPts):
    for j in range(0, nPts):
        pts2[i*nPts + j,:] = [xi[i], yi[j]]

press_linear = interp_linear(np.unique(pts1[:,0]), np.unique(pts1[:,1]),
    z1.reshape(4,5), pts2[:,0], pts2[:,1])

# Press, bicubic
press_cubic = interp_cubic(np.unique(pts1[:,0]), np.unique(pts1[:,1]),
    z1.reshape(4,5), pts2[:,0], pts2[:,1])

# Display
fig_scipy = plt.figure()
fig_press = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig_scipy.add_subplot(121, aspect = 'equal')
ax1.set_title("Scipy (linear)")
ax1.contourf(xi, yi, scipy_linear.reshape(nPts, nPts), color_ticks)
ax1.scatter(pts1[:,0], pts1[:,1], color = 'k', s = 2)

ax2 = fig_scipy.add_subplot(122, aspect = 'equal')
ax2.set_title("Scipy (cubic)")
ax2.contourf(xi, yi, scipy_cubic.reshape(nPts, nPts), color_ticks)
ax2.scatter(pts1[:,0], pts1[:,1], color = 'k', s = 2)

ax3 = fig_press.add_subplot(121, aspect = 'equal')
ax3.set_title("Press (linear)")
ax3.contourf(xi, yi, press_linear.reshape(nPts, nPts).T, color_ticks)
ax3.scatter(pts1[:,0], pts1[:,1], color = 'k', s = 2)

ax4 = fig_press.add_subplot(122, aspect = 'equal')
ax4.set_title("Press (cubic)")
ax4.contourf(xi, yi, press_cubic.reshape(nPts, nPts).T, color_ticks)
ax4.scatter(pts1[:,0], pts1[:,1], color = 'k', s = 2)

plt.show()
```

The interpolations from my own functions give what I *think* is right:
[image]
while the interpolations from `griddata` result in (notice the differences, particularly on the bottom right part of the contours):
[image]

Am I using `griddata` correctly? If so, where do the differences come from? Is one result "better" than the other? One explication I could see is the way I compute the derivatives in my bicubic function, but this would not explain the discrepancies between the two bilinear methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> between the two bilinear methods.

Your method may be bilinear, but SciPy's is not. This can be seen already from the piecewise linear gradients in the image, and the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) confirms:

> tesselate the input point set to n-dimensional simplices, and interpolate linearly on each simplex.

So, SciPy's interpolant is locally `a*x + b*y + c` while yours is `a*x*y +
 b*x + c*y + d`

To get bilinear interpolation of unstructured data with SciPy, use [SmoothBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline) with kx=1 and ky=1 (bilinear), and s=0 (no smoothing). (But it seems you'll need more data points than in this example to achieve s=0.)

For bilinear interpolation off a rectangular grid, there is  [RectBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline), again with kx=1 and ky=1.

As for the difference in cubic versions, there are [too many details in the procedure](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator) to expect that your interpolant will exactly agree with SciPy's.